# FatalThrowableError in ItemsController.php line 97: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Tags: php, laravel, syntax-error, fatal-error

Hi i'm pretty new on Laravel and i've been looking for errors the last hour and can't find it. Hope you can help me (i can't even use "php artisan route:list")

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $item = Item::find($id);
    $item->name = $request->name;
    $item->pompadour = $request->pompadour;
    $item->description = $request->description;
    $item->save();

    return redirect('/items')->with('warning', 'Your item ' . $item->name . ' has been updated.');

}
```

(Where it ends is line 97)

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION)
```

This is the error ( php artisan route:list ) as I mentioned before
Hope you can help me.

Route code:

```
Route::put('item/{id}', ['as' => 'items.update', 'uses' => 'Backend/ItemsController@update']);
```

Comment: Add your whole controller code. I imagine you're missing a `}` somewhere. What IDE are you using? Generally, they'll point this out for you.

Comment: If you can't use `php artisan route:list` that means 99% of time that you messed up your code structure. Look around wrong intends and brackets in your code - both in route list and controller code

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek my route list is perfect. I don't know why still gives me this error : "Class App\Http\Controllers\Backend/ItemsController does not exist "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function edit($id)
{
     $item = Item::find($id);
     return view(items.edit)->with('item', $item);
}
```

A view name have to be a string, so:

```
public function edit($id)
{
     $item = Item::find($id);
     return view('items.edit')->with('item', $item);
}
```

Should solve your problem.

Also simple tip: Act with syntax errors as they are a fact, as syntax errors are not runtime errors (your code did not even start execution stage) so it can not really be a bug, but simple human mistake. If you post about syntax error provide as much code as you can, it will make life easier for everybody so we won't have to guess where is the faulty line of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Item;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ItemsController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

        $items = Item::all();

        return view('backend.item.list')->with("items", $items);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('backend.item.form');
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // mejora:
        // $item = new Item($request->all());
        $item = new Item;
        $item->name = $request->get('name');
        $item->pompadour = $request->get('pompadour');
        $item->description = $request->get('description');
        $item->outstanding_image = '';
        $item->save();

        //Session::flash('flash_message', 'El item ' . $item->name . ' ha sido creada exitosamente!');

        return redirect('/items');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $item = Item::find($id);

        //return view('items.show')->withItem->($item);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
         $item = Item::find($id);
         return view(items.edit)->with('item', $item);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        // delete
        $item = Item::find($id);
        $item->delete();

        // redirect
        return redirect('/items')->with('notice', 'El item ' . $item->name . ' ha sido eliminado correctamente.');
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $item = Item::find($id);
        $item->name = $request->name;
        $item->pompadour = $request->pompadour;
        $item->description = $request->description;
        $item->save();

        return redirect('/items')->with('warning', 'El item ' . $item->name . ' ha siedo editado con exito.');

    }
}
```

This is my entire code. Hope it helps. My T_FUNCTION error was the last " }".